# Puedo definir una palabra antes de main?

Tags: c

Quiero poner: #define BLOCK 500
esto va antes de main o dentro del mismo? desde ya muchas gracias

Comment: ¿ Has probado ? Porque la prueba es bastante sencilla ...

Answer (score 0):

Para responder a esta pregunta antes debemos entender cómo funciona el proceso de compilación.

Cuando queremos compilar código fuente, por ejemplo "hola.h", el compilador ejecuta una serie de pasos, siendo el primero de ellos el precompilador. El precompilador busca una serie de directivas y macros en el código:

- Los `#include` se reemplazan por el contenido del archivo a incluir
- Las macros se reemplazan por el código equivalente
- Se elimina código que no pase las directivas `#ifdef`, `#if`, etc.
- ...

Una vez el precompilador termina su tarea, le llega el turno al compilador en sí mismo. Éste cogerá código fuente puro (ya sin directivas) que ha generado el precompilador y creará código objeto. Un símil del código objeto lo encuentras en los componentes para PC (una fuente de alimentación por ejemplo) ya que dicho componente viene completamente ensamblado por dentro y te ofrece una serie de conectores (los cables que salen de dicha fuente de alimentación) para terminar de interconectarlo con otros elementos para crear un sistema completo.

Para crear el binario final falta un último paso, el enlazador. Este programa coge los diferentes códigos objeto y los une entre sí para formar el binario final.

Pues bien, la directiva `#define` la gestiona el preprocesador, mientras que la función `main` es responsabilidad del compilador... son dos etapas diferentes y, por tanto, **da absolutamente igual** dónde pongas el `#define`. La única restricción es que debe encontrarse antes de cualquier uso de la macro que defina... si no el precompilador se quejará porque no reconoce el símbolo.

```
#define A 1

int main()
{
  #define B 2

  printf("%d %d", A, B);
}
```

Una prueba un poco más oscura pero que demuestra que son etapas totalmente diferentes:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define A "hola"); }
#define H int
#define L puts(
#define O main() {

H O L A
```

Lo que sucede en este caso es que el precompilador reemplaza las macros por su código equivalente, generando un código similar al siguiente:

```
// [Contenido de stdio.h]

int main()
{
    puts("hola");
}
```

Y esto será lo que reciba el compilador, que, como ves, es código C totalmente legal.

Answer (score -1):

Se sitúa antes de main como en el siguiente ejemplo:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define BLOCK 500

int main(){
(codigo)
}
```